# Fetch/Remove all unused assets (by plugin)

Tags: plugin-development, assets, delete

The title is self-explanatory, but I need to buid a service function to remove unused assets, or at least to fetch those in order to delete found assets after.

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
//First fetch all ids from elements table
$allIds = craft()->db->createCommand()->select('id')->from('elements')->where([
    'not like', 'type', 'Asset'
])->queryColumn();

// query for all related Assets -> assets that are used somewhere
$usedAssetCriteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset);
$usedAssetCriteria->relatedTo = $allIds;
$usedAssetCriteria->limit = null;
$usedAssets = $usedAssetCriteria->ids();

// query for all assets not in the list of the used one
$unUsedCriteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset);
$unUsedCriteria->id = 'and, not ' . implode(', not ', $usedAssets);
craft()->assets->deleteFiles($unUsedCriteria->ids());
```

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason, it returns all assets. (I replaced the delete part by a var_dump)

Comment: sry, my mistake, you have to replace the `.find()` with an `.ids()` I updated my answer. It works now for all assets with no relation

Comment: Does this also cover assets linked in redactor fields?

Comment: No, that's only one reason why you should avoid using images in rich text fields. The advantage of craft is: you can avoid using images in those fields and instead create a matrix element with a text and image input. However, if you want include those you would have to loop through every rich text in every field (including matrix elements) and parse the images